# Smartsheet: Give A Group Full Access To All Workspaces

Tags: c#, smartsheet-api

I've done a little bit of work with the Smartsheet API in the past, but this new task is a bit out of my wheelhouse. My workplace's Smartsheet admin wants to have access to all workspaces within our company's Smartsheet in order to keep track of everything that's going on.

Since there doesn't appear to be a way to do this from within Smartsheet, I've been tasked with creating a program that uses the API to accomplish this task.

I believe I can figure out the actual granting of access, but only for one sheet or workspace at a time. I was wondering if there is a way to get a list of all sheets or workspaces in order to perform the access grant operation on each. I'm hoping there might even be a way already to grant a blanket access to all workspaces.

I've searched through the API documentation, the example program, and here on stackoverflow and I haven't seen anything that would help put me on the right track.

If anyone knows of any resources that can be of assistance or knows a way to do this, I would very much appreciate the help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *system administrator* can list all sheets in the organization with `smartsheet.UserResources.SheetResources.ListSheets()` as per http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?csharp#list-org-sheets

Then you can evaluate or update the sharing options for each sheet. Note that you will have to use the Asssume-User feature to impersonate the sheet owner. Call `.SetAssumedUser()` on the `SmartsheetBuilder()` when constructing the client.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you!
It appears their documentations is slightly out of date.  


The current version of the command is: `smartsheet.UserResources.SheetResources.ListOrgSheets()`